# OpenGL render on command

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

What I am trying to do is get a couple of textures from my program and render them into one texture and send it back, but I only want it to render them when I tell it to.  Is there some way to get rid of opengl's main loop so I can render when I want it to, or can I pause the main loop until I want to render the next texture?

Edit: I'm using Glut and Glew right now.

Comment: Render will always be called. But what's wrong with `if(skipRender) return;` ?

Comment: I've never heard of skipRender, so I don't know how it would work

Comment: `skipRender` is not a language or framework feature. It's just a made up boolean. You need to become more comfortable with C++ in general before tackling a beast like OpenGL.

Comment: It sounds like you're using some third party API with OpenGL that's controlling the main loop for you, like glut.  Do you know if that's the case?

Comment: yup thats it, I always forget that glut isn't part of opengl, guess it looks like that was my main problem

Comment: Ok, so somewhere in you're code you have to be calling glSwapBuffers or glFlush, depending on whether or not you're using double buffering.   You have complete control over when rendering happens through those functions.  I would recommend getting a good book ( I highly recommend the OpenGL Superbible) and read through it.  It would help you learn everything you need to know about OpenGL.

Comment: I currently have Interactive Computer Graphics, but I've mostly used it for the examples and then skimmed the chapters for the information I didn't know.  All the example had glutMainLoop in it so I assumed it was needed

Answer (score 7):

OpenGL has no main loop. Are you using some kind of framework? What makes you think you cannot control when renders happen? You should have control over when you swap buffers or call `glFlush()`. It sounds more like you need to simply better understand C++ control structures, but it's hard to know with the severely limited information presented in your question.

Comment: Ahh, yeah, I was using glut which has a main loop, I guess that makes sense now.  I thought it would be something simple like this I just could find out what it was.

Comment: @ParkerOlson OK. Personally, I recommend learning SDL. You can easily form an OpenGL context and then create (or not create) your own event loop. You can do your render and then stop.